# How to programmatically create list of buttons that fill client browser based on its resolution in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am new to ASP.net web application development. I try to create a page that contains a number of buttons (based on the data from database), all the buttons have the same size, and fill the client browser (no scroll bars on either side).

The questions that I have are:

1. How can I get client browser's resolution? (By jQuery)
2. Is the size of each button will be Resolution / Number of Buttons?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code we can troubleshoot or are you just asking for someone to do it for you?

Comment: So far, I tried to get the window width and height by using jquery like  $(document).ready(function () {
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend learning a templating framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It allows you to quickly develop grid-based web pages that you can easily throw a customized template on.